# Acquire::Retries does not seem to handle 404 errors

Tags: apt, docker

I am dealing with somewhat unreliable corporate mirrors of canonical repositories. By unreliable I mean I get some 404 and 502 errors while trying to install several packages in a ubuntu:20.04 based docker image.

I created the following `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom` file:

```bash
Acquire::Retries "3";
Acquire::https::Timeout "240";
APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
APT::Install-Suggests "false";
Debug::Acquire::https "true";
```

It does handle as expected 502 errors:

```bash
#12 12.65 GET /ubuntu_debian_valid_internet/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-minimal_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb HTTP/1.1

#12 15.17 Answer for: https://.../ubuntu_debian_valid_internet/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-minimal_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
#12 15.17 HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway

#12 142.3 GET /ubuntu_debian_valid_internet/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-minimal_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb HTTP/1.1

#12 144.4 Answer for: https://.../ubuntu_debian_valid_internet/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-minimal_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
#12 144.4 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
#12 144.4 Date: Thu, 11 Aug 2022 07:46:23 GMT
#12 144.4 Content-Type: application/x-debian-package
```

But it seems that for 404 errors (I can get some, and if I retry later, it works), there is no automatic retries. Is that expected behavior??
Sure I could (and in fact I did) wrap my apt update / install in a loop to force retry, but it seems like a hack:

```
&& while !\
        apt update \
       ;do echo "apt update has failed... Waiting before next try"; sleep 1; done\
    && while !\
        apt install\
         curl \
         apt-utils \
         iputils-ping \
         nano \
         gridsite-clients\ 
         cppcheck \
...
         npm \
       ;do echo "apt install has failed... Waiting before next try"; sleep 1; done\
```